# Java/Oracle : Find all Dependent Rows and Update Them

Tags: java, oracle, metadata

I have an Oracle table (COMBO_VALUES) which has been referenced by many other tables. for example 1 record in COMBO_VALUES may have been referenced by 100 different tables.

I want to find all the related records (Their ID and Table Name) pointing at a COMBO_VALUES record so that I can update them later on.

I'd prefer using Java code in this problem which can make use of Oracle Metadata to gather the data I'm looking for (I'm not proficient in PL/SQL).

By the way I don't want to alter my table to have a "CASCADE" option. all I want (at least right now) is to find dependent rows Id and Table names.

Thank you...

Comment: Take a look at `SELECT * FROM user_constraints WHERE constraint_type='R'`

Comment: This just gives me the reference constraints... their name doesn't seem to be usable for me...

Comment: Sorry, this gives you table and referenced table und column: `SELECT UC.TABLE_NAME,
          UC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
          UCC.TABLE_NAME,
          UCC.COLUMN_NAME
     FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS  UC,
          USER_CONS_COLUMNS UCC
    WHERE UC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = UCC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
      AND uc.constraint_type = 'R'
    ORDER BY UC.TABLE_NAME,
             UC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
             UCC.TABLE_NAME,
             UCC.COLUMN_NAME;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a class which does exactly what I want:

1. Try to delete a Record which may have been referenced by other records
2. Find All Children and change their references to a new Id
3. Finally delete the record

here's the code I came up with (Sorry it may not be good enough) :

```
public class RowFinder {
    boolean autoCommit;

    public RowFinder(boolean autoCommit) {
        this.autoCommit = autoCommit;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RowFinder rowFinder = new RowFinder(false);
        rowFinder.findRows("YOUR_TABLE_NAME", "PRIMARY_KEY_FIELD_NAME", "OLD_ID", "NEW_ID_FOR_CHILDREN");
    }

    public void findRows(String tableName, String columnName, String oldId, String newId) {

        Connection connection = null;
        java.sql.Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin@DB_IP_ADDRESS:1521:SID", "USER", "PASS");
            connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            System.out.println(String.format("\nTrying to Delete %s with Old ID: '%s' and Update Children with New ID: '%s'", tableName, oldId, newId));

            boolean flag = true;
            long counter = 1;
            while (flag) {

                try {
                    String deleteQuery = String.format("delete from %s where %s = %s", tableName, columnName, oldId);
                    statement.executeUpdate(deleteQuery);
                    flag = false;
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                    String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
                    //TRYING TO FIND THE CONSTRAINT NAME FROM ERROR - YOU CAN CHANGE IT ACCORDING TO YOUR PROJECT SETTINGS
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(PROJECT_NAME\\.(.*)\\)");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(errorMessage);
                    String referenceName;
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        referenceName = matcher.group(1);
                        String constraintTableQuery = String.format("SELECT ucc.table_name,ucc.column_name FROM user_cons_columns ucc WHERE ucc.constraint_name = '%s'", referenceName);
                        try {
                            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(constraintTableQuery);
                            resultSet.next();
                            String constraintTableName = resultSet.getString(1);
                            String constraintColumnName = resultSet.getString(2);
                            String updateQuery = String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s = '%s' WHERE %s = '%s'", constraintTableName, constraintColumnName, newId, constraintColumnName, oldId);
                            statement.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
                            System.out.println(String.format("%s. Updated Child Located at : %s => %s",counter++,constraintTableName,constraintColumnName));
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Matcher didn't find anything... Exiting...");

                        if (autoCommit)
                            connection.commit();
                        else
                            connection.rollback();

                        statement.close();
                        connection.close();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                if (autoCommit){                
                    System.out.println("Deleted the Record and Changed its Children.");
                    connection.commit();    
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Rolling Back Changes...");
                    connection.rollback();
                }

                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an ugly way, however this is what you have asked for. You could join **all_cons_columns** and **all_constraints** views to get the **parent-child** information based on the primary key-foreign key relationship. Once you get the parent table, child table and the referencing column name, you could later do a **MERGE** on the child table with the matched rows form parent table.

For example,

```
SQL> column owner format a10
SQL> column parent_table format a15
SQL> column child_table format a15
SQL> column column_name format a15
SQL> column constraint_name format a15
SQL> column referenced_key format a15
SQL> column constraint_type format a15
SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> SELECT a.owner,
  2    a.table_name parent_table,
  3    b.table_name child_table,
  4    a.column_name,
  5    a.constraint_name,
  6    b.constraint_name referenced_key,
  7    b.constraint_type
  8  FROM all_cons_columns a ,
  9    all_constraints b
 10  WHERE a.owner           ='SCOTT'
 11  AND a.constraint_name = b.r_constraint_name
 12  AND a.table_name      ='DEPT';

OWNER PARENT_TABLE CHILD_TABLE COLUMN_NAME CONSTRAINT_NAME REFERENCED_KEY  CONSTRAINT_TYPE
----- ------------ ----------- ----------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
SCOTT DEPT         EMP         DEPTNO      PK_DEPT         FK_DEPTNO       R

SQL>
```

So, above query gives me the parent and child table information and the column name which is referenced. Based on this information, use **MERGE** statement:

```
MERGE child_table c
USING parent_table p
ON (p.key = c.key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET...
```

Remember, you cannot merge the column you are using to join in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle **doesn't support** mechanism of updating values in foreign tables, when pk in main changed. You'll need to update values manualy in whole referrence tables. Read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm#sthref3088).

Comment: That's why I asked for a manual Java code... one that iterates over all columns that may point to our record...

Comment: there is no chance for java to make something with constraints that can't do oracle.

Comment: also it is a bad idea updating pk, better to build new one based on old.

Comment: with such task you can make some method in ora, that will fill all necessary data